# Python 'if' and 'while' conditions not working

Tags: python, if-statement, while-loop, conditional-statements

I am writing a simple Python program. It's supposed to read two sorted lists from tab-delineated file and merge them into a single sorted list. The algorithm isn't too tough but Python seems to be ignoring the conditions in my loops and if statements!

Here's my input file:

```
1   2   3   10
7   9   100
```

Here's the relevant bit of code with print commands for debugging:

```
print 'list1 len =' + str(len(list1)) + ', list2 len = ' + str(len(list2))
while (i < len(list1)) or (j < len(list2)):
    print 'i = ' + str(i)
    print 'list1[i] = ' + str(list1[i])
    if (list1[i] < list2[j]):
        print str(list1[i]) + ' < ' + str(list2[j])
        output.append(list1[i])
        i += 1
    else:
        output.append(list2[j])
        j += 1
```

The program reads in the correct values but seems to always read the if-condition as true at every iteration.

```
list1 len =4, list2 len = 3
i = 0
list1[i] = 1
1 < 7
i = 1
list1[i] = 2
2 < 7
i = 2
list1[i] = 3
3 < 7
i = 3
list1[i] = 10
10 < 7
i = 4
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "q2.py", line 22, in <module>
     print 'list1[i] = ' + str(list1[i])
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Not only is the if-statement not working (`10 < 7` isn't right!), it's also failing at the `while` loop, since `'i'` gets to 4, the size of `list1`. What is happening?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want `and`, not `or`, in your `while` loop test:

```
while i < len(list1) and j < len(list2):
```

`(i < len(list1)) or (j < len(list2))` is going to be true if **one of those tests is true**. So `i` doesn't *have* to be smaller than `len(list1)` as long as `j` is smaller than `len(list2)`. `False or True` is still `True`.

Next, your `if` test is most likely comparing *strings*, not integers. Strings are compared lexicographically:

```
>>> 'abc' < 'abd'
True
>>> 'ab' < 'b'
True
>>> '10' < '2'
True
```

The first characters are compared before other characters are tested, and `'1'` sorts before `'2'`.

Compare integers instead:

```
if int(list1[i]) < int(list2[j]):
```

You probably want to convert your file inputs to integers the moment you read them, however.