# basic not equals to operation

Tags: python, python-3.x

Need help with better understanding of not equal to in conjunction with and/or statements inside if loop.

## Question

In the following code, for 1st for loop I was expecting the integers except 6 & 9 (but instead of 'or' if I use 'and' then I am getting desired output).

The 2nd for loop outcome is OK.

```
a = [2, 6, 1, 9, 6, 3, 9]
for x in a:
    if x != 6 or x != 9:
        print(f"1st for loop {x}")
for y in a:
    if y == 6 or y == 9:
        print(f"2nd for loop {y}")
```

## Output of the above code:

```
1st for loop 2
1st for loop 6
1st for loop 1
1st for loop 9
1st for loop 6
1st for loop 3
1st for loop 9
2nd for loop 6
2nd for loop 9
2nd for loop 6
2nd for loop 9
```

Comment: The `or` operator means "if either one of the terms is True, then it is True", so when you write then `or` that way you accept both any term that is not `6 and 9`, so its a tautology.

Comment: [De Morgan's Laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws) will sometimes help you navigate expressions such as these.

Comment: In your question, you said "`except 6 & 9`" so for your desired output use `and` operation!

Comment: Or to be Pythonic, `if x not in (6, 9)` :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python 'if' and 'while' conditions not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44188347/python-if-and-while-conditions-not-working)

Answer (score 3):

If you consider the subclauses of the condition

```
x != 6 or x != 9
```

when `x = 6`:

```
x != 6 --> not true, it definitely is 6
x != 9 --> true, as it (still) is 6
```

Combining these with `or` ("if either or both of these conditions is true") naturally yields true in both `x = 6` and `x = 9` cases.

Answer (score 1):

Your puzzle is a misunderstanding of the way boolean operators work. You are expecting `if x!=6 or x!=9:` to do the exact opposite of `if y==6 or y==9:`. But that is not how `and` `or` and `not` work.

If you have a test `A or B` then the opposite of that test is `not (A or B)`. If you want to remove the brackets then the equivalent way to write the test is `not A and not B`. Note, `and` not `or`.

You are testing numbers and you want to reject 6 and 9. If you say *is it not equal to 6?* and you get the answer Yes, and you respond *okay, is it also not equal to 9?*, then every number, including 6 and 9, will pass the test. Why? Because when you test 9, it is not equal to 6, so 9 passes the first test. When you test 6, it fails the first test, but it is not equal to 9, so 6 passes the second test. And your code says you accept the number if *either* test is successful. That is why you need `and` not `or`. *Both* tests have to be successful.